# Deploy on heroku with Gitlab CI suddenly JSON::ParserError

Tags: ruby, heroku, gitlab-ci

My deploy process of an app to heroku is suddenly not working today and I can't find anything for this.

I have an error but I can't find any way to debug it..

Here is what I have :

```
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY --skip_cleanup

Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.3
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed dpl-heroku-1.10.16
3 gems installed
authentication succeeded       // Some tries it is displayed some other it's not
checking for app myHerokuApp   // Some tries it is displayed some other it's not
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse': 859: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html> (JSON::ParserError)
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Application Error</title>
    <style media="screen">
      html,body,iframe {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      html,body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.1.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-heroku-1.10.16/lib/dpl/provider/heroku/generic.rb:55:in `handle_error_response'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-heroku-1.10.16/lib/dpl/provider/heroku/generic.rb:66:in `check_app'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/lib/dpl/provider.rb:188:in `block in deploy'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/lib/dpl/provider.rb:186:in `deploy'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dpl-1.10.16/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/dpl:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/dpl:25:in `<main>'
```

The fact is that my CI was working yesterday. If I run again an old pipeline, it will not crash. I checked :

- All dependencies are still the same
- ruby version is the same
- dpl version is the same
- my heroku app name is correct

Comment: It's probably not your process - `heroku` is currently having issues: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2398